# Calling the minimum value using join function mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have two tables:

```
hotels
id, hotel

rooms
id , hotel, type, stay, price
```

At the second table there are more than one row with the same room type at different prices depending on the room meal (stay).

How can I call just for one row from the second table which has the minimum price for this room type?

My code as following

```
select h.hotel
     , r.hotel
     , r.stay
     , r.type
     , r.price 
  from hotels h 
  LEFT 
  JOIN rooms r
    ON r.hotel = h.hotel
 where r.type = '$rtype1 
 GROUP 
    BY r.hotel 
 ORDER 
    BY r.price asc
```

$rtype is the value sent by the visitor through the input field

Comment: `rooms.type='$rtype1` is that typo?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: $rtype is the value sent by the visitor through the input field

Comment: Just a thing to note: using user input directly in an sql query is a security risk and allows [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are many ways to avoid this, some are described in [this tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic way to do it would be to use a sub query to get the first item for each hotel, and then join that to get the other details. However in this case this isn' such a good idea as several rooms can probably have the same low price. But something like this:-

```
SELECT h.hotel,
        r.stay,
        r.typee,
        r.price
FROM hotels h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT hotel, 
            MIN(price) AS min_price
    FROM rooms
    WHERE r.type = '$rtype1'
    GROUP BY hotel
) sub0
ON sub0.hotel = h.hotel
LEFT OUTER JOIN rooms r ON r.hotel = sub0.hotel AND AND r.price = sub0.min_price AND r.type = '$rtype1'
```

Another was is to (ab)use the GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions. This gets all the details for each room for each hoten in price order, separated by a comma (default from GROUP_CONCAT) and then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first details. This struggles when the items may naturally contain the delimiter.

```
SELECT h.hotel,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(r.stay ORDER BY r.price), ',', 1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(r.type ORDER BY r.price), ',', 1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(r.price ORDER BY r.price), ',', 1)
FROM hotels h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rooms r ON r.hotel = h.hotel AND r.type = '$rtype1' 
GROUP BY h.hotel
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It has brought the minimum price as I want but the problem is it doesn't bring the other fields of the same row but it is bringing the values of the first row having the hotel name I am looking for its rooms.

Comment: For example: the min_price is 600 and r.stay should be half board. but while  the first result has the price of 700  and r.stay of Full board. So what I will have from the query the min price is 600 and the r.stay is full board and this is not true. Can you help me for this please? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Mido - the solutions I have put should not do that (that is the result I would expect with your original query)

Comment: Did you think this was becoz there is the same value of min-price for more than one row?

Comment: I mean multiple rooms have an equal cheapest price in a hotel and i only want one result (any one)

Comment: @Mido - The first solution I gave would return 2 rows in that situation (as I highlighted in the answer). The 2nd will give one row, and potentially I can see if returning a mixed up row but that should be easy to solve by more fully specifying the orders in the GROUP_CONCAT functions (but to give those details I would need to know the order you want to specify).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time. I appreciate it. I knew where was the mistake and it is working perfectly now.